# Defer parts of the expression

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

Is there a way to Defer only parts of the expression? 
For example,  I have

```
a=1;
```

and then I want the expression to be shown as`a = 1;`by using`Defer[a = Evaluate[a]]`,But the actual output is just

```
a = Evaluate[a]]
```

Is there away to only Defer part of an expression?

Comment: Maybe `Defer[a = x] /. x -> a` or `Defer[a = #] &[a]`?

Comment: or `With[{x = a}, Defer[a = x]]`?

Comment: Both solution works, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert into held expressions in a number of ways:

Using `ReplaceAll (/.)`: `Defer[a=x]/.x->a`

Using function evaluation: `Defer[a=#]&[a]`

Using `With` : `With[{x=a}, Defer[a=x]`

Example:

```
a = 2; z = 4; w = 5;
{Defer[a + w = x + z] /. x->a, Defer[a + w = # + z]&[a], With[{x = a},Defer[a + w = x + z]]}
(* {a + w = 2 + z, a + w = 2 + z, a + w = 2 + z} *)
```