# Delete Part of Deferred Expression

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, hold

Szabolcs provided an elegant answer to [my previous question about printing executable code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158901/easy-printing-of-executable-code) that uses [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html):

```
SetAttributes[echo, HoldAll]
echo[expr_] := (CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Defer[expr], CellDingbat -> ">"]; expr)
```

I'd like to tweak it a little if possible, to not print out options that aren't set.  Here is a typical example of the kind of application I have in mind.  `ex2` is a function that calls `NDSolve` and takes an optional argument `opts`, which can pass options to `NDSolve`.

```
ex2[eqns_, unks_, tmax_, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{ndsolveopts},
  ndsolveopts = NDSolveOpts /. Flatten[{opts, Options[ex2]}];
  With[{options = Evaluate[Sequence @@ ndsolveopts]},
    echo@NDSolve[eqns, unks, {t, 0, tmax}, options]]
];
Options[ex2] = {NDSolveOpts -> {}};
```

This works as expected:

```
ex2[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, 10,
  NDSolveOpts -> {AccuracyGoal -> 16}]
```

> > NDSolve[{n'[t] == (1 - n[t]) n[t], n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 16]
>
> {{n -> InterpolatingFunction[...]}}

This includes an ugly `Sequence[]` that I'd like to not see:

```
ex2[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, 10]
```

> > NDSolve[{n'[t]==(1 - n[t]) n[t],n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}, Sequence[]]
>
> {{n -> InterpolatingFunction[...]}}

Is there anyway to modify `echo` to prevent its output?

[This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47930/defer-parts-of-the-expression) shows how to change a part of an expression inside `Defer`.  Can I delete part instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases):

```
SetAttributes[echo,HoldFirst];
echo[expr_]:=(
    CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[
        DeleteCases[Unevaluated@Defer[expr], Verbatim[Sequence][], {2}],
        CellDingbat->">"
    ];
    expr
)
```

Comment: My other uses of this function require replacing the levelspec `{2}` with `Infinity` but this is great, thanks!